# Tensorflow error - dimensions of logits and labels must be same

Tags: tensorflow

I was training a convolutional network in tensorflow.

My code is, its the squeezenet code which I am trying to train on tiny imagenet having 200 classes from stanford's website.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
from scipy.misc import imread

NUM_CLASSES = 200

def fire_module(x,inp,sp,e11p,e33p):
    with tf.variable_scope("fire"):
        with tf.variable_scope("squeeze"):
            W = tf.get_variable("weights",shape=[1,1,inp,sp])
            b = tf.get_variable("bias",shape=[sp])
            s = tf.nn.conv2d(x,W,[1,1,1,1],"VALID")+b
            s = tf.nn.relu(s)
        with tf.variable_scope("e11"):
            W = tf.get_variable("weights",shape=[1,1,sp,e11p])
            b = tf.get_variable("bias",shape=[e11p])
            e11 = tf.nn.conv2d(s,W,[1,1,1,1],"VALID")+b
            e11 = tf.nn.relu(e11)
        with tf.variable_scope("e33"):
            W = tf.get_variable("weights",shape=[3,3,sp,e33p])
            b = tf.get_variable("bias",shape=[e33p])
            e33 = tf.nn.conv2d(s,W,[1,1,1,1],"SAME")+b
            e33 = tf.nn.relu(e33)
        return tf.concat([e11,e33],3)


class SqueezeNet(object):
    def extract_features(self, input=None, reuse=True):
        if input is None:
            input = self.image
        x = input
        layers = []
        with tf.variable_scope('features', reuse=reuse):
            with tf.variable_scope('layer0'):
                W = tf.get_variable("weights",shape=[3,3,3,64])
                b = tf.get_variable("bias",shape=[64])
                x = tf.nn.conv2d(x,W,[1,2,2,1],"VALID")
                x = tf.nn.bias_add(x,b)
                layers.append(x)
            with tf.variable_scope('layer1'):
                x = tf.nn.relu(x)
                layers.append(x)
            with tf.variable_scope('layer2'):
                x = tf.nn.max_pool(x,[1,3,3,1],strides=[1,2,2,1],padding='VALID')
                layers.append(x)
            with tf.variable_scope('layer3'):
                x = fire_module(x,64,16,64,64)
                layers.append(x)
            with tf.variable_scope('layer4'):
                x = fire_module(x,128,16,64,64)
                layers.append(x)
            with tf.variable_scope('layer5'):
                x = tf.nn.max_pool(x,[1,3,3,1],strides=[1,2,2,1],padding='VALID')
                layers.append(x)
            with tf.variable_scope('layer6'):
                x = fire_module(x,128,32,128,128)
                layers.append(x)
            with tf.variable_scope('layer7'):
                x = fire_module(x,256,32,128,128)
                layers.append(x)
            with tf.variable_scope('layer8'):
                x = tf.nn.max_pool(x,[1,3,3,1],strides=[1,2,2,1],padding='VALID')
                layers.append(x)
            with tf.variable_scope('layer9'):
                x = fire_module(x,256,48,192,192)
                layers.append(x)
            with tf.variable_scope('layer10'):
                x = fire_module(x,384,48,192,192)
                layers.append(x)
            with tf.variable_scope('layer11'):
                x = fire_module(x,384,64,256,256)
                layers.append(x)
            with tf.variable_scope('layer12'):
                x = fire_module(x,512,64,256,256)
                layers.append(x)
        return layers

    def __init__(self, save_path=None, sess=None, restore=True, data=None):
        """Create a SqueezeNet model.
        Inputs:
        - save_path: path to TensorFlow checkpoint
        - sess: TensorFlow session
        - input: optional input to the model. If None, will use placeholder for input.
        """
        self.images = tf.placeholder('float',shape=[None,None,None,3],name='input_image')
        self.labels = tf.placeholder('int32', shape=[None], name='labels')
        self.layers = []
        x = self.images
        self.layers = self.extract_features(x, reuse=False)
        self.features = self.layers[-1]
        with tf.variable_scope('classifier'):
            with tf.variable_scope('layer0'):
                x = self.features
                self.layers.append(x)
            with tf.variable_scope('layer1'):
                W = tf.get_variable("weights",shape=[1,1,512,1000])
                b = tf.get_variable("bias",shape=[1000])
                x = tf.nn.conv2d(x,W,[1,1,1,1],"VALID")
                x = tf.nn.bias_add(x,b)
                self.layers.append(x)
            with tf.variable_scope('layer2'):
                x = tf.nn.relu(x)
                self.layers.append(x)
            with tf.variable_scope('layer3'):
                x = tf.nn.avg_pool(x,[1,13,13,1],strides=[1,13,13,1],padding='VALID')
                self.layers.append(x)
        self.classifier = tf.reshape(x,[-1, NUM_CLASSES])
        self.optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.002, beta1=0.85, beta2=0.97)

        if restore:
            saver = tf.train.Saver()
            saver.restore(sess, save_path)
            self.predicted_class = self.class_names[np.argmax(self.classifier, axis=1)]

        else:
            print(self.classifier.shape)
            self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=self.labels, logits=self.classifier))
            self.training_op = self.optimizer.minimize(self.loss)
            self.train()

    def load_images(self, path):
        # First load wnids
        with open(os.path.join(path, 'wnids.txt'), 'r') as f:
            wnids = [x.strip() for x in f]

        # Map wnids to integer labels
        wnid_to_label = {wnid: i for i, wnid in enumerate(wnids)}
        print("started loading")
        # Use words.txt to get names for each class
        with open(os.path.join(path, 'words.txt'), 'r') as f:
            wnid_to_words = dict(line.split('\t') for line in f)
            for wnid, words in wnid_to_words.items():
                wnid_to_words[wnid] = [w.strip() for w in words.split(',')]
        print("loading done")

        self.class_names = {}
        for i in range(200):
            self.class_names[i] = [wnid_to_words[wnid] for wnid in wnids]

        X_train = []
        y_train = []
        for i, wnid in enumerate(wnids):
            if (i + 1) % 2 == 0:
                print('loading training data for synset %d / %d'
                      % (i + 1, len(wnids)))

            # To figure out the filenames we need to open the boxes file
            boxes_file = os.path.join(path, 'train', wnid, '%s_boxes.txt' % wnid)
            with open(boxes_file, 'r') as f:
                filenames = [x.split('\t')[0] for x in f]
            num_images = len(filenames)

            X_train_block = np.zeros((num_images, 3, 64, 64), dtype=np.float32)
            y_train_block = wnid_to_label[wnid] * \
                            np.ones(num_images, dtype=np.int64)
            for j, img_file in enumerate(filenames):
                img_file = os.path.join(path, 'train', wnid, 'images', img_file)
                img = imread(img_file)
                if img.ndim == 2:
                    ## grayscale file
                    img.shape = (64, 64, 1)
                #X_train_block[j] = img.transpose(2, 0, 1)
            X_train.append(X_train_block)
            y_train.append(y_train_block)

        # We need to concatenate all training data
        X_train = np.concatenate(X_train, axis=0)
        y_train = np.concatenate(y_train, axis=0)
        X_train = np.transpose(X_train, (0, 2, 3, 1))
        #print(X_train.shape, y_train.shape)
        return (X_train, y_train)

    def train(self):
        self.training_images = self.load_images("/home/jatin/codes/projects/objectdetect/object/imagenet/tiny-imagenet-200")
        #print(self.training_images[0].shape)
        self.num_epochs = 100
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        #print("initiated")
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
            for epoch in range(1):
                sess.run([self.training_op],
                         feed_dict={self.images: self.training_images[0], self.labels: self.training_images[1]})
                print("Doing training")
                if epoch % 10 == 0:
                    save_path = saver.save(sess, "./sqnet/squeezenet.cpkt")


snet = SqueezeNet(restore=False)
```

But running this gives me error -

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [0,200] and labels shape [500]
 [[Node: SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits = SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, Tlabels=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Reshape, _arg_labels_0_1)]]
```

The error essentially corresponds to the line -

```
self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=self.labels, logits=self.classifier))
```

However the first dimension of X_train and y_train is same. 
It would be a great help if anybody could tell me.

Comment: as you errors tells, your classifier is trained to predict 200 classes, but the labels has different shape. Please do `print(self.labels)` to check what it outputs

Comment: check the shape arg here `self.labels = tf.placeholder('int32', shape=[None], name='labels')`

Comment: hey @user2906838, thanks for responding. Here self.labels have the dimensions (500,1) which is the number of images. But self.images is showing (0,200) instead of (500, 200)

Comment: self.labels should be representing the number of labels, i.e image category, not the images input as much as I can tell.